# Launch4j Support of Console and GUI applications

Tags: maven, launch4j

We have a java application that uses Launch4j to create a windows .exe. We achieve this using the org.bluestemsoftware.open.maven.plugin, which works great. I have one inquiry however. Recently I added cmd line functionality, and found that using the GUI header didn't pass arguments when run from the .exe. OK, that makes sense.

Using the Console Header works as intended (arguments are passed). However, now when we run it in GUI mode, I get the command window in the background, no pretty splash screen, and my window name is lost. Again, this makes sense, its a CONSOLE header now. But i need both functionalities.

Is there a way to support BOTH headers in one .exe?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am stuck in the same ditch!